# Directories enumeration by errors. CVSS3.1 and remediation

Tags: defense, enumeration

Let's consider this scenario.
If I browse to `https://www.example.com/existentdirectory` the web application shows this error "directory listing is denied".

If I browse to `https://www.example.com/nonexistentdirectory` the web application shows this error "file directory is not found".

To me this would represent a chance for the attacker to enumerate directories and gain information on the target.

I would assign the following CVSS3.1 vector:

`CVSS:3.1/AV:N/AC:L/PR:N/UI:N/S:U/C:L/I:N/A:N`

But what about the remediation part? Is it really needed?
Would it be counterproductive advise to use a generic error for both responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to determine a correct CVSS score as the internal tree structure is not exactly what we can call a "secret".
So the confidentiality impact has to be discussed.

Gaining information about the target makes furthers attacks simpler, but it is not an attack.
This difference is sometimes materialized by the concept of "non compliance" which is different than "vulnerability".

The remediation for this specific example is often to capture and log every error (so you get notified when there is an error 500 and other important ones) and to display a generic error message with a code 200 OK to the browser.
This way, you can also get rid of many web scanners